# Flutter: how to make Drawer z-index on top of all widget with Layout builder?

Tags: android, flutter, responsive, drawer, flutter-layoutbuilder

I'm building a responsive flutter app. i use layout builder to achieve that. I also need to open a drawer on my screen. Then I faced the problem that the second screen was piling up on top of my drawer.
i need a drawer to appear above all my widgets. Is there a workaround to achieve this with a layout builder?

**if you want to try ,you can clone this repository: [Flutter responsive drawer](https://github.com/pota-too/responsive-drawer-flutter-)**

preview:

[image]

i want the drawer show up on top of all page.

here some summary code (full code you can check on github link ) [1](https://github.com/pota-too/responsive-drawer-flutter-):

main_screen.dart

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Responsive(
        mobile: Column(
          children: const [Expanded(child: Page1()), Expanded(child: Page2())],
        ),
        tablet: Row(
          children: const [
            Expanded(flex: 1, child: Page1()),
            Expanded(flex: 2, child: Page2())
          ],
        ),
        desktop: Row(
          children: const [Expanded(child: Page1()), Expanded(child: Page2())],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

page1.dart

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page1> createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: const Text("Page 1"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

page2.dart

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: const SafeArea(
        child: Text("Page 2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

responsive.dart

```
class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;
  const Responsive({
    Key? key,
    required this.desktop,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.tablet,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// mobile < 650
  static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 650;

  /// tablet >= 650
  static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 650;

  ///desktop >= 1100
  static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1500;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      if (constraints.maxWidth >= 1500) {
        return desktop;
      } else if (constraints.maxWidth >= 650) {
        return tablet;
      } else {
        return mobile;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned @Mohamed Reda, by put the drawer on main screen to make it on top all widget.
Then to make access the drawer button are using `scaffoldKey`.

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Responsive(
          mobile: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                },
              ),
              const Expanded(child: Page1()),
              const Expanded(child: Page2())
            ],
          ),
          tablet: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      const Page1(),
                    ],
                  )),
              const Expanded(flex: 2, child: Page2())
            ],
          ),
          desktop: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  const Page1(),
                ],
              )),
              const Expanded(child: Page2())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the wrong parts of the code:

1. you put the drawer at the wrong page, you put it for just the first page like this

   ```
   @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(),
         drawer: const MyDrawer(),
         body: Container(
           alignment: Alignment.center,
           color: Colors.blue,
           child: const Text("Page 1"),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

so, you should delete the drawer from here and put it at the main_screen.dart

2. do the same last step for the appBar and put it at main_screen.dart
3. It's recommended for Any screen to have one Scaffold widget and you have it at main_screen.dart, so delete it from page1 to make it like page2

I hope that solved your problem.

Comment: thank you for your response. actually this not really  what i want. because main_screen is a `LayoutBuilder`
if i put the drawer there ,then when its on tablet and desktop , the `appbar` will appear in all over screen , and that really takes up space for page 2 in my apps.

Comment: but Thank you,  its give me another idea to call drawer with `scaffoldKey`